# How can i store separate image in separate field with single php code

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I have two separate image field and two separate cell in my table. I want to save separate image in those cell. I can repeat the following program but I think this wouldn't be the wise one. What can i do here?

```
<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="featuredImg">
<input type="file" id="topImg" name="topImg">

$permitted  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
$file_name  = $file['featuredImg']['name'];
$file_size  = $file['featuredImg']['size'];
$file_temp  = $file['featuredImg']['tmp_name'];

$div             = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_ext        = strtolower(end($div));
$unique_image    = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext;
$uploaded_image = "../images/uploads/".$unique_image;

move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image);
$query = "INSERT INTO aboutafc(featuredimage, topimage) VALUES ('$uploaded_image', '$topImage')";
```

Comment: You could use a loop,  `foreach(['featuredImg','topImg'] AS $field)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
foreach(['featuredImg','topImg'] AS $field){
    $permitted  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
    $file_name  = $file[$field]['name'];
    $file_size  = $file[$field]['size'];
    $file_temp  = $file[$field]['tmp_name'];

    $div             = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext        = strtolower(end($div));
    $unique_image    = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext;
    $uploaded_image = "../images/uploads/".$unique_image;

    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image); 
}

//-Note- this wont work as it is, logically it's incompatible.
$query = "INSERT INTO aboutafc(featuredimage, topimage) VALUES ('$uploaded_image', '$topImage')";
```

Personally I would store the images in a separate table with a Many To Many relationship, and some other data like type of image ( what field its from ).

That would resolve the issue of having to save them to the DB outside of the loop.  I don't like the idea of that at all ( to much room for errors when they are saved outside of the loop )

To fix that you have to do something like this

```
$images = [];
foreach(['featuredImg','topImg'] AS $field){
  //...
  $unique_image = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext;
  $images[] =  $unique_image;
  move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image);
}

if( count($images) != 2 ){
     //Error checking before saving files in the DB
}

$query = "INSERT INTO aboutafc(featuredimage, topimage) VALUES (:image1, :image2)";

$stmt = $PDO->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':image1'=>$images[0],':image2'=>$images[1]]);
```

Please notice I fixed your SQL Injection issues..

Also note my use of `$unique_image` I would strongly recommend not saving the full path.  Paths change, and you should not give users access to the file path only the name.  You open yourself up to Directory Traversal attacks if you give them access to the path.

So you have 2 security issues.

[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

[Directory Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack)

Comment: Thanks for your hard effort, I tried your first code.. and this is storing only 2nd image(topimage). But i think we are close to solve the problem. now i will try your 2nd way... as a novice php learner i am bit discomfortable in PDO. so i am going to try it in other way.

Comment: Brother can you rewrite the program without PDO as a learner it's rolling over my head.

Comment: PDO is simpler then Mysqli, it really is.  Also it has way more ways to pull out data. I haven't used anything else for about 4years except on here.